# How to compare two string in apache free marker

Tags: regex, freemarker, data-processing

I have below scenario in `apache free marker.`

```
str1= Shruti
```

`str2`  it can be`( "Shruti" ,"shruti", shruti,'Shruti' or SHRUTI)`

if string 2 is either with `double quote` or `single quot`e or plain, we need to return it true. also it should be case insensitive.
How can I ignore single quote and double quote in string if it contains and compare?

basically I want to compare 2 strings. if it contains "single quote or double quote" it should ignore. I tried using `str1=str2?remove_beginning(""")?remove_end(""")` but it is giving error.

Comment: Please edit the question to point out why you think it's relevant to the [tag:apache] tag before you add it a third time. Hint: Read the tag's description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace()` and match the quotation marks by escaping them with backslashes `\"` and `\'`. I also used `trim()` to remove leading and trailing spaces and `lower_case()` to ignore case. 
I tried the following out in the [Online FreeMarker Tester](https://try.freemarker.apache.org/)

```
str1 = "\"Hi\""
str2 = "'hi'"
```

```
<#if str1?trim?replace("\'","")?replace("\"","")?lower_case == str2?trim?replace("\'","")?replace("\"","")?lower_case>
  The two strings are equal
  ${str1?trim?replace("\'","")?replace("\"","")?lower_case} = ${str2?trim?replace("\'","")?replace("\"","")?lower_case}
  
</#if>
```

> The two strings are equal
>
> hi = hi

---

Here is a function that you can use for comparing two strings.

```
<#function is_equal x y>
  <#return x?trim?replace("\'","")?replace("\"","")?lower_case == y?trim?replace("\'","")?replace("\"","")?lower_case>
</#function>

<#if is_equal(str1,str2)>
  The two strings are equal
</#if>
```

Comment: thank you @Evan . Could you please answer this as well, Please?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62032594/contain-in-apache-free-marker